# Axios send too multiples request after submiting the form

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, axios, nuxt.js

I started working on small project using Laravel and Nuxt Js, so i have created a small for to add users in the database. every thing is going well, i have a small issue, my axios script send multiple request like a loop :

this is the full code :

```
<script>

import $ from 'jquery'
import Swal from 'sweetalert2'
import toastr from 'toastr'
import Vue from 'vue'
Vue.component('pagination', require('laravel-vue-pagination'))

export default {
  layout: 'app',
  data () {
    return {
      laravelData: {},
      formFields: {},
      search: null,
      refresh: false
    }
  },
  watch: {
    refresh () {
      this.store()
      this.refresh = false
    }
  },
  mounted () {
    $('a.just-kidding').hide()
    this.index(1)
  },
  methods: {
    index (page = 1) {
      this.$axios.$get('/customer?page=' + page).then((response) => {
        this.laravelData = response
        this.refresh = true
      })
    },
    store () {
      const formData = $('#add-customer').serialize()
      return this.$axios.$post('/customer/store', formData).then((response) => {
        this.refresh = true
      })
    },
    find () {
      if (this.search === '') {
        this.index()
      } else {
        this.$axios.$get('/customer/find?customer=' + this.search).then((response) => {
          this.laravelData = response
        })
      }
    },
    destroy (customerId) {
      Swal.fire({
        title: 'Are you sure?',
        text: "You won't be able to revert this!",
        type: 'warning',
        showCancelButton: true,
        confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',
        cancelButtonColor: '#d33',
        confirmButtonText: 'Yes, delete it!'
      }).then((result) => {
        if (result.value) {
          // this.$Progress.start();
          this.$axios.$get('/customer/destroy?customer=' + customerId).then((response) => {
            if (response.success) {
              toastr.success(response.error, 'Ahoy Hoy !!', { 'positionClass': 'toast-top-left' })
              this.refresh = true
            } else {
              toastr.error(response.error, 'Owh :( !!', { 'positionClass': 'toast-top-left' })
            }
          })
          // this.$Progress.finish();
        }
      })
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

and here is my controller :

```
public function store(Request $request)
{

    DB::transaction(function () use ($request){
        $customerQuery = Customer::create($request->post('general'))->id;
        $shippingInfos = array_merge(array('customer_id' => $customerQuery), $request->post('address'));
        $shippingQuery = Shipping::create($shippingInfos);
        return true;
    });
}
```

i have created a Middleware page called cors in my laravel,

```
    <?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

class Cors
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        return $next($request)
        ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
        ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PUT, PATCH, DELETE, OPTIONS')
        ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type, Authorization');
    }
}
```

Comment: The code you provided does not give enough context on where the issue may be originating from... Perhaps if you could add more code samples...

Comment: I cannot see anything intrinsically wrong here. Are the requests all the same? how are you calling store()?

Comment: What are the multiple requests? Is it actually multiple POST requests, or is it an OPTIONS followed by a POST? If it's the latter, that's normal. It's because of CORS and pre-flight requests.

Comment: @MattU can ,  you double check my question, just edited

Comment: Is it an infinite loop? If so, it's probably because you're setting `this.refresh` in the watcher for that property. A watcher function can have two params `newValue` and `oldValue`. It's generally a good idea to check if the value is different before processing the actions in the watcher method.

Comment: However, in your case you may just need to check `if (newValue === true)` before running the `store` method and setting `refresh` to false.

Comment: @MattU can you give an example of the code 
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  watch: {
    refresh () {
      this.store()
      this.refresh = false
    }
  },
```

This will cause an infinite loop, because you're changing `this.refresh` in the watcher function that's *monitoring* `this.refresh`, which will re-trigger the watch function, which will change it, which will trigger the watcher, which will change it, which will trigger the watcher, which will change it, which will trigger the watcher, which will change it, which will trigger the watcher, which will change it...

You get the point.

Comment: you alright, how can i updated my table after submiting the form is there any other way or suggestion please